# Twitter O-Auth Basics

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I was using V1.0 of the REST API to simply pull twitter status updates into a website which was nice and easy! Now that API has gone, I believe I need to use O-Auth and create an App to do anything? I find the whole O-Auth thing quite confusing, does anyone have any useful links to a step by step process of creating a basic twitter app, how a user allows you to access their timeline (accepts access from the app?) then actually create a request and pull data, Twitter docs are just too much to digest at the moment.

Comment: Just went through this myself check out my answer over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049821/setting-up-twitter-api-getting-the-last-few-tweets/17057693#17057693

Comment: That's great thankyou so much, so as I understand it a user doesn't have to allow you (your app) access to the user timeline it's only if you need to do more complex things like tweet on their behalf and such, basically twitter just wants track usage of the API?