# Display Twitter feed v1.1 and Authenticating

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I used to display a customized twitter feed on one of my clients sites using API v1. I got the JSON file using `http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/username.json` and then parsed it. Now that twitter has switched to API v1.1 I am using this `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=my_screen_name` and I get the error: `{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}` due to the fact that I am not authenticated to make such a request. I have been looking through the documentation to no avail, any help figuring out how to use OAuth to authenticate my requests would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just answered this over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049821/setting-up-twitter-api-getting-the-last-few-tweets/17057693#17057693