# How to read latest Tweet according to Latest Twitter API

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to fetch latest tweet using latest twitter api and append that to my website div. I am using below code but not working.

So can please someone guide me how can i achieve this.I have tried below example but that is also expired now

[Setting up Twitter API, getting the last few Tweets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049821/setting-up-twitter-api-getting-the-last-few-tweets)

Answer (score 0):

You can set `data-tweet-limit="1"`

Example:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" 
    href="https://twitter.com/YOUR_HANDLE" 
    data-widget-id="YOUR_WIDGET_ID" 
    data-theme="light" 
    data-link-color="#2393aa" 
    data-chrome="noheader nofooter noborders noscrollbar transparent" 
    data-tweet-limit="1" 
    aria-polite="polite">Loading tweets...</a>

<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is it possible to fetch latest tweet without using Widget. Because i need to integrate that latest tweet text and tweet date in my design . This widget will add its own design.

Comment: You can use this: var tweet = $('.twitter-timeline li:first .e-entry-title').val();

Comment: Thanks Khalid.Can you please provide some reference according to latest Twitter API in jquery

Comment: I don't think there is such thing. You just need to inspect the rendered widget elements in your browser (right-click > Inspect element) and choose the appropriate jQuery selector to access whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the latest tweet by using the following jquery script.

```
<div class="tweet-item">
   <a class="twitter-timeline" 
     href="https://twitter.com/YOUR_HANDLE"  
     data-theme="light" 
     data-link-color="#2393aa" 
     data-chrome="noheader nofooter noborders noscrollbar transparent" 
     data-tweet-limit="1" 
     aria-polite="polite">Loading tweets...</a>
</div>

<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Then using jquery, I used this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var target = document.querySelector('.twitter-item');

            var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
                LoadTweet("twitter-widget-0"); 
            });

            var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

            observer.observe(target, config);

            function LoadTweet(item){

               if($('.twitter-item').hasClass("Loaded")){
                    // do nothing
               } else {
                    console.log("LoadTweet Fired "+ item);

                    var timelineId = item;
                    var media = $('#' + timelineId).contents().find('.timeline-Tweet-media img').attr("src") || "";
                    var tweet = $('#' + timelineId).contents().find('.timeline-Tweet-text').html() || "";
                    if(tweet){ 
                        $('.twitter-item').html("").html(tweet); }
                        $('.twitter-item').addClass("Loaded"); // prevent loop
                    }
              }
        }
 });

 </script>
```

The jquery script replaces the container with the tweet.  Hope this helps or points you in the right direction.