# trying to use twitter4j in a website...?

Tags: javascript, html, processing, twitter4j, adobe-brackets

I might well be the only person in the world trying to do this but I wrote a neat little program in Processing using the Twitter4j library which accesses the Twitter stream and displays Tweets based on given keywords, and now I want to implement into a website I'm about to write (in Adobe Brackets).

Using p5.js I'm able to access the basic functionality of Processing (in Javascript), but I have absolutely no idea how to use/access the Twitter4j library (since it's in Java).

Any ideas or alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a Java library from a JavaScript application. You'll have to find a JavaScript library and use that instead. If you want to stick with the Java library, then you'll only be able to deploy as a runnable jar or as an executable. You won't be able to embed it in a website.

Technically, you could deploy as a Java applet, but that's going to be more of a pain in the neck (for both you and your users) than just redoing it in JavaScript.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049821/setting-up-twitter-api-getting-the-last-few-tweets) is an answer that describes using Twitter's JavaScript library. [Here](https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript) is Twitter's documentation on using their API.