# How to get user information (like screen_name, description, etc) from id_str using Twitter API?

Tags: php, twitter

Suppose I have this text "retweet of tomgabi https://..." in a quoted_status, collected using https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json. When I open this link in a browser I can see a lot of information about the user (tweet, screen_name, description, etc). The URL change to https://twitter.com/wiltonpfilho/status/715320170655440896. How can I get, using the Twitter API, that user information (tweet, screen_name, description, etc) from this new URL. Can I access user information from id_str (in URL)?

Answer (score 0):

[Check this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049821/setting-up-twitter-api-getting-the-last-few-tweets)

So you REALLY don't want to do this client side anymore. (Just went through numerous docs, and devs suggest to do all oAuth server-side)

What you need to do:

**First**: sign up on https://dev.twitter.com, and make a new application.

**Second**: NOTE: Your Consumer Key / Secret along with Access Token / Secret

**Third**: Download Twitter oAuth Library (In this case I used the PHP Library https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth , additional library located here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries)

**Fourth**: (If using php) Make sure cURL is enabled, if your running on a LAMP here's the command you need:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

**Fifth**: Make a new PHP file and insert the following: Thanks to Tom Elliot http://www.webdevdoor.com/php/authenticating-twitter-feed-timeline-oauth/

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("twitteroauth/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php"); //Path to twitteroauth library you downloaded in step 3

$twitteruser = "twitterusername"; //user name you want to reference
$notweets = 30; //how many tweets you want to retrieve
$consumerkey = "12345"; //Noted keys from step 2
$consumersecret = "123456789"; //Noted keys from step 2
$accesstoken = "123456789"; //Noted keys from step 2
$accesstokensecret = "12345"; //Noted keys from step 2

function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
  $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
  return $connection;
}

$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);

echo json_encode($tweets);
echo $tweets; //testing remove for production   
?>
```

**And boom**, you're done. *I know this isn't a pure js solution but again reading through the new Twitter API 1.1 docs they REALLY don't want you to do this client site. Hope this* helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use [statuses/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/lookup).

For example, `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/lookup.json?id=715320170655440896`