# Do Twitter User Tokens Expire as of API v1.1?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I've been getting some (low frequency) of 'invalid or expired tokens' error when accessing twitter API. I've seen this question [Do twitter access token expire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357568/do-twitter-access-token-expire) that claims twitter tokens don't expire after a time period, but that's back from 2011.

Times have changed, do Twitter tokens now expire? If so, what is the time-frame?

Comment: If you get `Invalid or expired tokens`, you can reset your consumer keys/secret & user token & user token secret in [apps management page](http://apps.twitter.com)

Answer (score 1):

No, Twitter does not expire access tokens.

However, please keep in mind that an access token will become invalid if a user explicitly removes your application from their settings (or all of them if your Twitter application gets suspended). This explains the few errors you have seen in Twitter API responses.